# I want to show product list one column on left bar : magento version 1.5.0.1

Tags: layout, magento

I want to show product list one column on left bar : magento version 1.5.0.1

Left Bar is show :

- Image

- Product Name

- Price

- button cart

Thank You.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? What product types are these?

Answer (score 0):

Please edit your code in  catalog/products/list.phtml. The list.phtml contains both grid and list view. please edit in list view.